# Javascript: Creating a variable then using it in a prompt

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with this Guest prompt. I am trying to make it so that it sends a prompt with the default guest name and a random number for said guest. I don't think I am setting up the "guest" variable right, though I am also looking for other tips.

```
var guest = ("Guest" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999) + 1;);
var name = prompt("Enter your chat name:" + guest);
```

Comment: You're probably getting a syntax error in your console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` - F12 usually opens the console (useful for debugging)

Comment: I'm not super rich so I am using a school chromebook for messing with computers (Yea I know a chromebook) though with it being under school restrictions I don't have access to developer console.

Comment: In that case, debugging is going to be very hard. Not sure what to tell ya.

Comment: If this is a school tell them you are trying to learn to program and need to access the developer console to do so... I would hope they are supportive.

Comment: Yep, I have though I am making a Maze game in Gaming and Animation class right now already and im trying to get the IT team to add Visual Studio so I don't have to make this game in scratch. I submitted that form 3 weeks ago and my teacher still hasn't heard from them so I don't think I want to have to wait another 4 weeks to get a console, which is not even guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an extra `;` in the code:

```js
var guest = ("Guest" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999) + 1);
var name = prompt("Enter your chat name:" + guest);

console.log(guest);
console.log(name);
```